# How to avoid Duplicate objects in DB4o database

Tags: java, android, .net, android-sqlite, db4o

```
Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.rollNo = "44";
        s1.name = "kk";
db4o().save(s1);

Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.rollNo = "44";
        s2.name = "kk";
db4o().save(s2);
```

here I am saving two object s1 and s2 in DB4o Database and both object are saved even though they have duplicate information , what I want is same rollNo student should be saved only once just like relational databases using primary key. I know that DB4o save objects based on reference address, correct me if I am wrong. Please let me know if there is any way to achieve primary key functionality to avoid Data Redundancy in DB4o.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db4o tracks object by their identity. So if you create a new object with 'new', it will be considered a new object. If you want to update a object, you need to get that object and change it. So here:

```
Student toUpdate = db4o.query(new Predicate<Student>() {
    @Override
    public boolean match(Student student) {
        return pilot.rollNo.equals("44");
    }
}).get(0);

toUpdate.name ="newName";

db4o.store(toUpdate); // Updated
```

That's it. db4o allway's tracks the actual objects. Not the values.

Note that you can [add unique constrains](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/unique_constraints.htm) to avoid mistakes. For more about updating, see documentation: http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/basics/update_concept.htm

Comment: Thanks you very much for the reply with sample code, it works and I  liked the native way of object comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have 2 options:

1. Add a [UniqueFieldValueConstraint](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/unique_constraints.htm) to your configuration (in this case violations will be reported as exceptions)
2. Execute a query (which is basically what the UniqueFieldValueConstraint will do anyway) and check if such object already exists in the db.

Hope this helps.